# Automation with Selenium C# FirefoxDriver not working

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver to do some browser tests, I've got them working fine in Chrome and IE11, but Firefox isn't working.

Unlike the other browsers when the browser window opens in Firefox, it searches for the url, but after a waiting period of around 15 seconds it fails to navigate to the url.

Firefox says 'Server not found' error, yet it works in other browsers. One thing I've noticed is that the Firefox windows opened by me manually can navigate to any site, but if I use the Firefox window opened by Selenium and try to navigate to any url e.g google.co.uk, it also tries to navigate to it for 15 seconds and fails and has the server message, so I think there is something wrong with the browser window Selenium opens.

I am using:
Firefox 53.0
Selenium 3.4
GeckoDriver 0.16.1

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace TestSuiteTest
{
    class Test3
    {
        IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void Initalize()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        [Test]
        public void OpenFirefoxTest()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.testsite.co.uk/location");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("edit-distance-postal-code")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("edit-distance-postal-code")).SendKeys("SN2 8UH");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("edit-submit-store-location")).Click();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void EndTest()
        {
            //driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated,

Comment: Please check if the version of the geko driver and firefox are compatible, and also, whether you are using 32/64 bit versions of the firefox and driver.

Comment: Just tried two earlier versions of GeckoDriver (0.16.0 and 0.15.0) and still having same problem. I also tried earlier Firefox versions and had the same problem.

Comment: Hve you solved it yet?.